# How can I store objects into an ArrayList without them duplicating in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, duplicates

So i have some code that takes a bunch of data and creates objects from that data. Here is the pseudo code. The main class looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
storage.addObject(2, 20, Jake, JE);
storage.addObject(5, 34, Kate, KI);
storage.addObject(3, 26, Joe, JL);
```

Then another class called storage will create and store these objects into an ArrayList

```
public void addObject(int number, int age, String name, String code) {
Object newObject = new Object(number, age, name, code);
objects.add(newObject);
```

The problem that I am getting is that when I try

```
System.out.println(objects);
```

Each bit of data in the array list is storing multiple objects so the output looks like this

```
[2 20 Jake JE]
[2 20 Jake JE, 5 34 Kate KI]
[2 20 Jake JE, 5 34 Kate KI, 3 26 Joe JL]
```

I don't know why it's repeating the objects but I am trying to make it so 1 object is in 1 part of the arrayList so the output looks like

```
[2 20 Jake JE]
[5 34 Kate KI]
[3 26 Joe JL]
```

The object creating class has a toString part so that all of the data gets converted to a string
I'm not getting any compiling errors

Comment: You seems to print the list each time you add something, so it's kind of normal to see the previous added element no ?

Comment: [read this and update your question accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), currently this is a mess.

Comment: add `storage` and `Object` classes to clear your problem.

Comment: `System.out.println(objectToAdd);` instead?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wanted to just use generic objects but, this is how I would do it.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Storage storage= new Storage();
    storage.addObject(2, 20, "Jake", "JE");
    storage.addObject(5, 34, "Kate", "KI");
    storage.addObject(3, 26, "Joe", "JL");
    System.out.println(storage.objects);


}
```

}

Person

```
public class Person {
int number;
int age;
String name;
String code;
public Person(int number, int age, String name, String code){
    this.number = number;
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}
public String toString(){
  return number+" "+age+ " "+name+" "+ code;
  /*This will output [2 20 Jake JE, 5 34 Kate KI, 3 26 Joe JL].
  return "["+number+" "+age+ " "+name+" "+ code+"]";
  This will output [[2 20 Jake JE], [5 34 Kate KI], [3 26 Joe JL]].*/

}
```

}

Storage

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Storage {

ArrayList<Person> objects;

public Storage(){
    objects= new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addObject(int number, int age, String name, String code) {

    objects.add(new Person(number, age, name, code));
}
```

}

You can create your own toString() inside the Storage class if you want.

I tried to maintain the structure of your code but you probably do this more concisely.